PySpark write to BigQuery error: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;JJ)V
Heyyy, I can read from BigQuery using pyspark just fine, but writing to it seems impossible because this error keeps showing up:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;JJ)V

Im using the newest jars:
spark.jars.packages com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.41.1,\
                    com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.2.26

Or with some additional packages that might be the problem as I found on stackoverflow, but it still doesnt work:
spark.jars.packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,\
                    io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.69.0,\
                    io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.69.0,\
                    com.google.inject:guice:7.0.0,\
                    com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.41.1,\
                    com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.2.26

Would you have any ideas what is going on or which package is not compatible?
Also I tried these pyspark versions and they all throw the same error:
3.1.3
3.3.3
3.5.1

Java version is java 11.0.23 2024-04-16 LTS

com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core requires com.google.guava:guava jar yet you have overridden Guava with a newer version. Please verify if you are using right version of guava when you override by doing mvn dependency:tree
maven repositroy for google-cloud can be found at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/

Yeah, guava version gets overriden every time:
:: evicted modules:         com.google.guava#guava;23.5-jre by [com.google.guava#guava;33.3.1-android] in [default]
I dont understand two things: why is this guava  version not compatible if thats what the google packages force you to use by default?
Which version of guava should I use then?
